# MS Access delete Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-delete

I have  query in MS Access that produces a correct records result, but Access refuses to run the Query as a delete query?
Can any one help me rewrite this query to run in access.

```
Delete Table_A.*
FROM (SELECT Table_A.Main_RecID, Table_A.Fld_Unique_ID, Table_A.Actiontaken FROM Table_A 
WHERE Table_A.Actiontaken="MainRecord deleted")  AS Tmp_B 
LEFT JOIN Table_A ON Tmp_B.Main_RecID=Table_A.Main_Recid
WHERE (((Table_A.Actiontaken)<>"MainRecord deleted"));
```

If the "Delete" is replaced by a select or I ask for a datasheet view the Query produces what I would expect.  Which is a list of the records in the table that have the same Main_RecID as records with Actiontaken field = "MainRecord deleted" but do not have their Actiontaken field equal to "MainRecord deleted".

Access responds with the message "Could not delete from specified tables."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with this data in `Table_A` ...

```
Fld_Unique_ID Main_RecID Actiontaken
            1          1 MainRecord deleted
            2          1 
            3          2 MainRecord deleted
            4          2 something else
            5          3 something else
```

Note `Actiontaken` is Null in second row (where `Fld_Unique_ID` = 2).

Executing the `DELETE` statement below leaves this data in the table.

```
Fld_Unique_ID Main_RecID Actiontaken
            1          1 MainRecord deleted
            3          2 MainRecord deleted
            5          3 something else
```

```sql
DELETE
FROM Table_A
WHERE
    (
           Actiontaken<>'MainRecord deleted'
        OR Actiontaken Is Null
    )
    AND
    (
        DCount("*", "Table_A",
            "Main_RecID = " & Main_RecID
            & " AND Actiontaken='MainRecord deleted'") > 0
    );
```

If that's not what you're after, please show us sample data before and after `DELETE`.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for.  Sorry for the delayed response I've been otherwise engaged.  When I first looked at this query I immediately said it was not what I wanted,  but it does work in Access.  Thank you sir (or madame)  I take my hat off to you.